# xcode JSON trouble

Tags: xcode, json, ios5, ios5.1

I have a problem with this code right here:

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
    //parse out the json data
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSArray* announcements = [json objectForKey:@"clients"];

    NSLog(@"laag 1: %@", announcements);

    NSDictionary* announcement = [announcements objectAtIndex:0];

    NSNumber *status = [announcement objectForKey:@"status"];

    humanReadble.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", status];
}
```

I'm trying to fetch JSON data from [this](http://rs-hosting.nl/panel/serverstatus_json.php) URL. I know the fetching works, the NSLog displays it fine, but the problem begins at the NSDictionary. I did some tests with breakpoints and found that the error was there. This is a overview of my log:

```
2012-03-20 23:15:13.210 Json test 2[13248:f803] laag 1: {
    client =     (
                {
            companyname = xxx;
            datecreated = "2012-03-11";
            email = "xxxx";
            firstname = xxx;
            groupid = 0;
            id = 3;
            lastname = O;
            status = Active;
        },
                {
            companyname = "xxx";
            datecreated = "2012-03-02";
            email = "xxx";
            firstname = xxx;
            groupid = 0;
            id = 1;
            lastname = "xxx";
            status = Active;
        },
                {
            companyname = "";
            datecreated = "2012-03-08";
            email = "xxx";
            firstname = xxx;
            groupid = 0;
            id = 2;
            lastname = xxx;
            status = Active;
        },
                {
            companyname = xxx;
            datecreated = "2012-03-13";
            email = "xxx";
            firstname = xxx;
            groupid = 0;
            id = 4;
            lastname = "xxx";
            status = Active;
        }
    );
}
2012-03-20 23:15:13.212 Json test 2[13248:f803] -[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6821f30
2012-03-20 23:15:13.213 Json test 2[13248:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6821f30'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x13c7022 0x1558cd6 0x13c8cbd 0x132ded0 0x132dcb2 0x21a2 0x13c8e42 0x9379df 0x139b94f 0x12feb43 0x12fe424 0x12fdd84 0x12fdc9b 0x12b07d8 0x12b088a 0x11626 0x1c3d 0x1ba5)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

Can someone please help me out?

I use sdk 5.1, xcode 4.3 on lion 10.7.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object returned by `[json objectForKey:@"clients"]` in your code is actually a dictionary, not an array.  First you need to extract the "client" object (which is the array you want) from that dictionary.  You can do it like this:

```
NSDictionary *clients = [json objectForKey:@"clients"];
NSArray *announcements = [clients objectForKey:@"client"];
NSDictionary* announcement = [announcements objectAtIndex:0];
```